# SQL Server database restore question : how to restore database backup but merge with current data?

Tags: sql-server, restore

I need to restore a database to about 2 weeks back, I have nightly backups of the database. However I'm trying to avoid losing the data between now and 2 weeks ago.

If I restore the database to 2 weeks ago, will I lose all the data between then and today?

Is there a proper way to do this, or can I just use task>restore and pick my timeline?

Thanks all

Comment: If you restore a database to a backup made 2 weeks ago, of course you lose all the data since then. If you don't want to lose it why are you restoring?

Comment: Restore is an all-or-nothing thing (excluding tables split across file groups, that's a special case), so if you have no point in time where *all* data was present, you can't simply restore and be done with it. Restore the DB to a separate, new database, then write queries (or use any other mechanism for data transfer, like the Import/Export Data Wizard) to transfer data from old to new or the other way around. Note that you'll also have to deal with any inconsistent or duplicated data as a result from merging (which is why restore on its own could not possibly do this).

Comment: If you restore a database to as it was 2 weeks ago then of course you'll lose the most recent 2 weeks' data - that data didn't *exist* two weeks ago - if it was still there then the restore would have failed, wouldn't it.

Answer (score 1):

You can restore the backup to a different database, and then merge the newer data into the restored database.